# index a list of data.frames by a variable

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How to access a particular data.frame in a list of them?

`a` is a list of data.frames.

```
a$`1999`    ## returns 1 data.frame
a[1]$`1999` ## returns 1 data.frame
year = 1999
a$`year`    ## returns NULL
a[1]$`year` ## returns NULL
```

Why is this?

Comment: `a[[year]]` might work

Comment: That didn't work, but `a[[toString(year)]]` did, as did `a[[`year`]]` -- there should be backticks around `year`

Comment: @d.b if you want to submit that as an answer i'll accept it..